# Android. Не получается обновить данные с использованием SwipeRefreshLayout + LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, livedata, observer, swiperefreshlayout

В приложении используются принципы `Clean Acrhitecture`. Данные собираются и эмитятся в `data слое`. В моем случае используется `LiveData Builder + Coroutines`. `Observer` установлен во фрагменте.

После запуска приложения данные присваиваются `_profile` переменной в `ProfileFragmentViewModel`. Затем они отображаются в `Resource.Status.SUCCESS` блоке.

Когда я использую `viewModel.refreshProfile()`, это не дает ожидаемого эффекта, переменная `_profile` в `ProfileFragmentViewModel` не обновляется.

Таким образом, мне необходимо обновить данные после вызова метода `refreshProfile`. Пожалуйста, посмотрите мой код ниже и подскажите что нужно изменить, что бы добиться желаемого результата. Код упростил до минимума, но суть осталась та же.

**ProfileFragment.kt**

```
class ProfileFragment : DaggerFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModel: ProfileFragmentViewModel

    private val observer = Observer<Resource<Profile>> {
        when (it.status) {
            Resource.Status.LOADING -> {
                Timber.i("Loading...")
            }
            Resource.Status.SUCCESS -> {
                Timber.i("Success: %s", it.data)
                srl_profile.isRefreshing = false
            }
            Resource.Status.ERROR -> {
                Timber.i("Error: %s", it.message)
                srl_profile.isRefreshing = false
            }
        }
    };

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        srl_profile.setOnRefreshListener {
           srl_profile.isRefreshing = true
           viewModel.refreshProfile()
        }
        viewModel.getProfileLive().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, observer)
    }
}
```

**ProfileFragmentViewModel.kt**

```
class ProfileFragmentViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val profileUseCase: ProfileUseCase
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _profile = profileUseCase.getProfile()
  
    fun refreshProfile() {
       _profile = profileUseCase.getProfile()
    }
    fun getProfileLive() = _profile
}
```

**ProfileUseCase.kt**

```
class ProfileUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val profileRepository: ProfileRepository
) {

    fun getProfile(): LiveData<Resource<Profile>> {
        return profileRepository.getProfile()
    }
}
```

**ProfileRepository.kt**

```
class ProfileRepository @Inject constructor(   
   private val loginUserDao: LoginUserDao,   
   private val profileDao: ProfileDao   
) {

fun getProfile(): LiveData<Resource<Profile>> =
    liveData(Dispatchers.IO)
    {
        emit(Resource.loading(data = null))

        val profile = profileDao.getProfile()

        // Emit Success result...
    }
}
```

Comment: Кажется, проблема у вас в том, что вы подписываетесь во фрагменте на один экземпляр LiveData, а потом меняете его во ViewModel, соответственно, попимо утечек памяти вы не получаете изменений, т.к. подписаны на неизменяемую LiveData. Вам надо как-то сделать так, чтобы вы не меняли постоянно экземпляры LiveData в ViewModel, но использовали один и тот же экземпляр всегда.

Comment: Проверить моё предположение вы можете, например, как-то так: `fun refreshProfile() { println(_profile)
       _profile = profileUseCase.getProfile().also { println(_profile) }
    }` - выводится в логи должно что-то такое: `LiveData@234234` - если после собаки будут разные значения, то проблема именно в разных экземплярах.

Comment: У Вас немного неправильно сделано, но в общем, чтобы заработало надо fun refreshProfile() {
       _profile = profileUseCase.getProfile()
    } поменять на fun refreshProfile() {
       _profile.postValue(profileUseCase.getProfile().value)
    }

И поменять LiveData на MutableLiveData. Но это неправильно. Если все еще непонятно, то позже могу переписать Ваш вариант на более правильный.

Comment: @beeline09 спасибо! Да, там просто у меня еще используется навигатор, поэтому есть кое-какие нюансы. А с вами можно будет как-то связаться?

Comment: Да. Пишите в телегу @beeline09

Comment: @beeline09 ваш не находит в телеграмме. П.С. извиняюсь за столь поздний ответ

Comment: Номер здесь светить не хочу. Ищите по нику beeline09 в сети. Я один такой))

Comment: @beeline09 номер не нужно, но по нику не находит. Напишите мне, пожалуйста, - arty_199